# How Best to Prevent Malvertisement From Infecting my Computer?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, malware

The reason I ask this question is because I am currently using an Adblocker to block all advertisements. I don't particularly feel comfortable doing this however because I'm not supporting the developers and IT managers who run the sites with revenue from my traffic.

That being said, I've never had a malware infection ever since I installed the Adblocker. What are some settings I can mess with to more or less guarantee that my computer cannot be explicitly infected from loading advertisements? Note that does not mean that it should not be infected from clicking on them.

I'd love to get the guilt of using an Adblock off my chest being a computer engineer and developer myself, but I'm not sure it is safe.

For reference I'm using the latest version of Chrome with Windows 7.

Comment: You can create a white list of sites where you trust and allow adverts. It is easy to add any site you're on to this list.

Answer (score -1):

There might be also other good examples thru internet.

Maybe creating a program that add lines to a hosts-file, by parsing a website, I don't know well ?!

As example you could use the hosts-file of Win7 in your case.

> "C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"

```
# ads
  127.0.0.1 0101011.com 
  127.0.0.1 0427d7.se 
  127.0.0.1 0d79ed.r.axf8.net
  127.0.0.1 0pn.ru
  127.0.0.1 0qizz.super-promo.hoxo.info
  127.0.0.1 104231.dtiblog.com
```

e.g. [here](http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/)